# "No module named x.y" error in Heroku but works locally

Tags: django, heroku

My project works perfectly locally but a ModuleNotFoundError arises from my INSTALLED_APPS when I deploy the app on Heroku. Particularly: "No module named x.y", and AttributeError: "Module x has no attribute y"

My project structure is like this:

```
main
   -settings.py
x
   -__init.py__
   -y
         -__init.py__
```

and in my settings.py I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('x')

INSTALLED_APPS{
     'x.y'
}
```

This works fine locally, but triggers those two errors when I deploy the app on Heroku. Any help is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `x` contain an `__init__.py`? i.e. is `x` itself a package?

Comment: Per Django's document of [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps), the setting should be list of strings, not the `x.y` (without quotes). Why don't you use `'x.y'` (and remove `sys.path.append('x')` as well)?

Comment: Yes, both x and y have the init file (an empty one). As for whether x is a package, do I have to add more than an init file to make it work as a package? It also has its urls.py...

Comment: I forgot to write 'x.y' as a string in this post, but I have them as strings in my INSTALLED_APPS (I will edit the post now, sorry). Besides, the project does not work locally if I remove the sys.path.append.